# Pass arrays from a jsp to a function in a js file via the onload attribute in the body tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a jsp and a js files. I would like to pass arrays from the jsp to a function in the js file via the onload attribute in the body tag. How can I do that?

For example:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var indexNames  = ['chIndex', 'recordIndex'];
        var indexLocation = [0, 1];
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="addRowHandlers('row', 2, $indexNames, $indexLocation)">
```

The output is not correct and I think $indexNames and $indexLocation are not the right way to pass the arrays.

Of course, in this case, I can separate the array values into multiple parameters. I am just  want to make the javascript function more general. Thanks in advance.

Kenneth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hm.i don't know jsp 
but your example don't work because its javascript.
Аnd in onload function js machine don't know what is  $indexNames and $indexLocation variable.
If you want just to pass arrays in function:

```
<body onload="addRowHandlers('row', 2, indexNames, indexLocation)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var indexNames  = ['chIndex', 'recordIndex'];
        var indexLocation = [0, 1];
        window.onload =function() {
            addRowHandlers('row', 2, indexNames, indexLocation);
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: My problem was adding the $ to the variables. Thanks.